# org folding: show tags after the "...", not before?

Tags: org-mode

When parental level node, which contains both child items and tags, is folded by `tab`, the `...` indication for folded child items is associated with the tags rather than the node text.

for instance, it displays like:

```
*1st level node            :@tag1...
```

while I would like it to be:

```
*1st level node...      :@tag1
```

Is it possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible -- out of the box -- because the folded content is subsequent to where the tag ends. It is possible to copy the contents of tag(s), and use it as an overlay in addition to the ellipsis (and start the fold before the tag begins), but that is certainly not built-in behavior and would involve modifying the source-code for someone motivated with some free time on his/her hands.  In essence, the concept is that the tag will actually be folded/hidden and what is visible will be overlays in the form of an ellipsis *plus* a stretch spacer overlay *plus* a tag overlay.

Comment: @lawlist: could you convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: @Dan -- It would essentially be a duplicate of the answer below by akaihola on October 27, 2014, since it contains a direct quotation of my initial comment on October 20, 2014.  I don't really have anything else meaningful to add.

Comment: @lawlist: understood, but I'd rather not encourage the posting of answers that are simply quoting other people's comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lawlist's comment is actually an answer:

> No, that is not possible – out of the box – because the folded content is subsequent to where the tag ends. It is possible to copy the contents of tag(s), and use it as an overlay in addition to the ellipsis (and start the fold before the tag begins), but that is certainly not built-in behavior and would involve modifying the source-code for someone motivated with some free time on his/her hands. In essence, the concept is that the tag will actually be folded/hidden and what is visible will be overlays in the form of an ellipsis plus a stretch spacer overlay plus a tag overlay.